Proof of the existence of algebraic closed field by Artin
I am reading the proof of the existence of algebraic closed field in Dummit&Foote, which is given by Artin.

For every nonconstant monic polynomial $f = f (x)$ with coefficients in $F$, let $x_f$ denote an indeterminate and consider the polynomial ring $F[ . . . , x_f , . . . ]$ generated over $F$ by the variables $x_f$. In this polynomial ring consider the ideal $I$ generated by the polynomials $f (x_f )$. If this ideal is not proper, then $1$ is an element of the ideal, hence we have a relation
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}g_j(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)f_j(x_j)=1$$
for some $f_j(x_j)$'s in the set of generators or the ideal $I$, where $g_j\in F[ . . . , x_f , . . . ]$ and $x_{n+1},\cdots,x_m$ are the remaining indeterminates occurring in $g_j$'s.

Note that the ideal $I=\big<\ f\in F[x]-F\ \big|\ f\ \text{is monic}\ \rangle$ is not finitely generated, so I think that $1\in I$ does not necessarily provide a finite sum $\sum_{j=1}^{n}g_jf_j=1$, namely it may be $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}g_jf_j=1$. But why does the author directly assume that this sum is finite?

What does an infinite sum mean in the ring of polynomials over some arbitrary field?

You remind me that elements in the polynomial ring in infinite variables are polynomials in finite variables, thanks@MorA.

Just like the vector space generated by a set $A$ is the set of finite linear combinations $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i$ (where the $\lambda_i$ come from your base field and the $a_i$ come from $A$), the ideal generated by a set $A$ is the set of finite linear combinations $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i$ where now the $\lambda_i$s are elements in your base ring and the $a_i$ are elements from $A$. In particular, the sum you're interested in is finite by the definition of elements in the ideal $I = \langle A \rangle$.
To see why this should be true, think about an inductive procedure for generating the ideal $I$:

We start with the subset $A \subseteq R$
This should be closed under $R$-multiplication and under sums, so we need to throw in elements that look like $\lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_2$ for $\lambda_i \in R$
This is still not closed under $R$-multiplication and sums. We need to throw in elements that look like $\mu_1 (\lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_2) + \mu_2 (\lambda_3 a_3 + \lambda_4 a_4)$ which we can expand into a polynomial in $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$.
This is also still not closed under the desired operations, but we can keep playing this game.
...

Eventually, after doing countably many steps, we'll be closed under the desired operations. And everything we added is something we needed to add, so this is the smallest ideal containing $A$, as desired. Note also that everything we added must have been added at some finite stage, so that all of our sums are finite! This is good, because it's not even clear how to make sense of anything other than a finite sum in a ring!

I hope this helps ^_^

We can make sense of infinite sums in the ring of real numbers, which has additional (metric) structure, but not in arbitrary rings

Thanks, I had misunderstood the definition of an ideal $I$ generated by a subset $S$ of a commutative ring $R$: it is $\big{\ \sum_{i=1}^{<\infty}r_is_i\ \big|\ r_i\in R,s_i\in S\ \big}$, not $\sum_i Rs_i$ as the sum of principal ideals.
